# Installing curl in Debian via archive

Tags: debian, curl, repository

I need to make a debian:9 container image work.

First the dockerfile failed in a

```
apt-get update -y
```

so i did:

```
RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backdoors.list
RUN rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

so now the apt-get update works fine. However, i need to install curl and i keep getting:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curl : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.52.1-5+deb9u10) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I dont know how to see if the package has been moved to another repository, and restoring the previous sources.list didnt work.
I also tried installing libcurl3 but it also doesnt work.

What is the correct way to solve this?

Comment: I also checked https://archive.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/c/ and obviously curl isnt there. So i suppose its still somewhere and i just have to find it?

Comment: I finally found the package here: `https://archive.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/c/` but i still dont know how to isntall it with apt-get. Adding `deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main` to sources.list didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

Since everything was ported to archive, i was using the wrong link. I should have changed from

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
```

to

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
```

Then, run

```shell
apt-get update
apt-get install curl
```